# Adding a plugin in tiny MCe throwing error

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am adding a plugin named akindicplugin for indian language support typing in my Tinymce editor i have grab the plugin from this site.
http://amiworks.co.in/talk/akindicplugin-transliteration-in-indian-lanuguages-for-tinymce/

And used as it is as shown in the example but for some unkown reason its throwing error
"ReferenceError: TinyMCE_Menu is not defined" in firefox console

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        language : "en",
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        safari_warning : false,
        plugins : "advlink, advimage,  preview, visualchars, media, nonbreaking, akIndicPlugin",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "styleprops, visualchars, media, nonbreaking, akIndicPlugin",
        debug : false,
        fullscreen_settings : {
            theme_advanced_path_location : "top"
        }
    });
</script>
```

It have tried editing the plugin editor_plugin.js file of the plugin but it seems like version issue anybody has any idea about what going with this...

Comment: Do you get the same error without the plugin?

Comment: The post says this plugin only supports TinyMCE 2.x. That's a pretty old version. Are you sure you're not using TinyMCE 3.x?

Comment: Nope no error without plugin..

Comment: @JohnFlatness where can i download TinyMCE 2.x i searched for it but didn't found...

Comment: SourceForge still has the old 2.x versions, [2.1.3 is the most recent](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinymce/files/TinyMCE/2.1.3/).

Comment: @JohnFlatness i have tried it with TinyMCE 2.x  but it didn't worked... :(

Comment: i strongly advise every tinymce admin to stick with the newest tinymce version if possible. otherwise tinymce might not be functional with newer browsers. looks you will have to rewrite the plugin yourself to make it tinymce 3.5.x compatible or to find another solution -> sry pal